# Returning a boolean value from a Circle Class C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to return a boolean value using a C++ class. It needs to be able to check whether circle A is the same size as circle B using an overload operator > which I have added as a public member in the class. In my int main it always seems to return false even when the circles are the same size.

Thanks, in advance.

Circle class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

//creating a constant pi that can't be changed
const double pi = 3.14159265;

class Circle
{
    //defining the private memeber variables
    private:
            double radius, xpos, ypos;

    //defining the public member variables
    public:
            //creating a constructor that takes all of the variables
            Circle(double r, double xposition, double yposition) {
                radius = r;
                xpos = xposition;
                ypos = yposition;
            }

            //creating a constructor that takes just the radius  
            Circle(double r) {
                radius = r;
                xpos = 0;
                ypos = 0;
            } 

            //creating a contructor that initialised everything to 0
            Circle() {
                radius = 0;
                xpos = 0;
                ypos = 0;
            }

            //defining the functions for radius, X-position, Y-position and area                       
            double getRadius() {return radius;}
            double getX() {return xpos;}
            double getY() {return ypos;}
            double getArea() {return pi*radius*radius;}

            //creating an overaload operator + to add the various properties of a circle together
            Circle operator+(Circle C) {
                radius = sqrt(this->getRadius()*this->getRadius() + C.getRadius()*C.getRadius()); //calculates the radius from the area
                xpos = (this->getX() + C.getX()) / 2.; //calculating the half way x position
                ypos = (this->getY() + C.getY()) / 2.; //calculating the half way y position
                return Circle(radius, xpos, ypos);
            } 

            //created an overload operator << that outputs information about the circle in a consistent manor
            friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Circle C) {
                return os << "radius = " << C.getRadius() << " at (x,y) = (" << C.getX() << "," << C.getY() << ")";
            }

            bool operator>(Circle C) {
                if (this->getRadius() > C.getRadius()) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
};
```

Int main ()

```
#include "Circle.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //defining the circles A and B
    Circle A(4.0,2.0,1.0);
    cout << "Circle A: " << A << endl;

    Circle B(4.0,5.0,6.0);
    cout << "Circle B: " << B << endl;

    //Adds A and B using the overload operator +
    Circle C = A + B;

    //Outputs the formatted text using the overload operator <<
    cout << "Circle C: " << C << endl;


    bool test;
    Circle D(4.0,2.0,1.0);

    if (A > D) {
        test = false;
    }
    else if (D > A) {
        test = false;
    }
    else {
        test = true;
    }

    cout << boolalpha << test << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that in C++ you'd traditionally overload `operator<` to define ordering. There's no particular reason you *couldn't* use `operator>` instead, but all the algorithms in the standard library (for one example) use `operator<` instead of `operator>`.

Answer (score 0):

"In my int main it always seems to return false even when the circles are the same size"

It will surely return false when circle are of same size as your condition is:-

```
  if ( this->getRadius() > C.getRadius() ) 
      return true;
```

everything other than this would return false. If you want to return true when your circle are of same size then make it:-

```
  if ( this->getRadius() < C.getRadius() ) 
      return false;
  else 
      return true;
```

EDITED IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT:-

Then probably you can use enum if want to to test three different scenarios:-

```
if ( this->getRadius() > C.getRadius() )
    return ENUM_GREATER;
else if ( this->getRadius() == C.getRadius() )
    return ENUM_EQUAL;
return ENUM_LESSER;
```

Comment: I think he means that `test` is `false`, which only happens if `A > D` or `D > A`.

Comment: I am required to return true when this->getRadius() > C.getRadius()

Answer (score 0):

`A.r` is `4.0`. `D.r` is also `4.0`. Neither `D > A` nor `A > D` is true. `>` checks for real greater than. If you want to have greater-or-equal use `>=` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your `operator+` modifies the left-hand operand. So, this line modifies `A` :

```
Circle C = A + B;
```

(including the `radius` member). So, by the time you compare `A` to `D`, `A`'s `radius` is no longer `4.0`.

The `operator+` can be modified as follows to fix this :

```
Circle operator+(const Circle& C) const {
    double r = sqrt(this->getRadius()*this->getRadius() + C.getRadius()*C.getRadius()); //calculates the radius from the area
    double x = (this->getX() + C.getX()) / 2.; //calculating the half way x position
    double y = (this->getY() + C.getY()) / 2.; //calculating the half way y position
    return Circle(r, x, y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work :-). Is there a way to modify the code so it doesn't change A

Answer (score 0):

When you do the following you are changing the value of A's radius

```
Circle C = A + B
```